# Solve code issue - string identity testing

Tags: shell

Please for help with shell script. I really dont understand where is problem. Where I write to the Input variable for example /home/Kovi/Deskop/netlist.exe I still get true answer but the extension "exe" is not "scs". I also try "==" but it didnt working. Please some advice. Thank you very much.

```
echo -n "Insert Entire Path (with file name and it's extension) of Input Netlist > "
read Input
if [ "${Input##*.}"="scs" ];
    then echo "Patch verification is succesful.;
    else echo "Patch verification is failed, script was aborted. File dont exist or is empty or unreadable or is not spectre netlist."
         error_exit;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You *must* include spaces  around the equals sign.

```
if [ "${Input##*.}" = "scs" ];
```

`[` is a command name, not part of the `if` statement's syntax, and it needs separate arguments for each part of the expression it is to evaluate. That is, it will not parse `a=b` as a comparison between `a` and `b`; you must write `a = b`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I absolutely didnt noticed this mistake. Thanks you again